# SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, tomcat, mime-types

I am developing a Jsp-Servlet application.
I deployed the application using Eclipse with Default Tomcat 7.

However after deploying the application, in Chrome/Firefox the UI gets rendered properly.
Where as in IE10 or later is showing this warning in console and none of the UI elements are loaded.

```
SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch
```

This is how the css files are referred

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/rpt.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
...............
</html>
```

How do I solve this issue?

**Update** If I run the site in Compatible mode, it's rendering fine. But how should I make it work even if it's not enabled.

**I can see that Type is not coming as text/css. But Why?**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok,

I found that there's no way of doing from server side [tomcat] and tried with web.xml too.
Then I found a workaround using a Filter Implementation

```
   @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        if(request.getHeader("accept")!=null && request.getHeader("accept").contains("css")){
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/css");
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, response);
    }
```

I explicitly set `text/css` for css requests. Then it's working fine.