# css file is not rendered in IE9 because in response Content-Type is not set

Tags: java, javascript, css, weblogic9.x

When I use IE9 I am getting "CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch" error in developer tool console and css is not apply and the web page is not align.

When I see the detail view of the response the Content-Type header is missing.

So how can I add text/css as Content-Type response header?

Do I have to add some configuration to the weblogic server settings?

Comment: You've kind of buried your main question under a lot of irrelevant information. The main question is: "**How do I ensure that `main.css` is served with the correct `Content-Type` header in WebLogic 9.x?**", right?

Comment: yes. served with Content-Type as text/css

Comment: i have update the question for specific information

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087170/sec7113-css-was-ignored-due-to-mime-type-mismatch