# Style on page is lost with SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am gettin the following error only in IE9 (compat mode is ok):

> SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch
>
> SEASONING_STYLES_DIRECTORY960.css

```
<link href="SEASONING_STYLES_DIRECTORY960.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link href="SEASONING_STYLES_DIRECTORYimprove.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
```

Firefox etc is ok, I believe that the code is ok as there is nothing special in it (as above).

Is there anything obvious I should be checking.

Update

The following if statement is used to call the stylesheet

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php print SEASONING_STYLES_DIRECTORY;?>ie/win-ie-all.css"/>
    <![endif]-->
```

In developer tools the result is 404 on type text/html. This works on IE8 with no issues.

Comment: The error message complains about the MIME type. Have you checked the MIME type?

Comment: here is a similar post.   check it out..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087170/sec7113-css-was-ignored-due-to-mime-type-mismatch

Comment: Hi, thank you. The following if statement is used to call the stylesheet
<!--[if IE]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php print SEASONING_STYLES_DIRECTORY;?>ie/win-ie-all.css"/>
 <![endif]-->

In developer tools the result is 404 on type text/html. This works on IE8 with no issues.

Comment: 404 means broken link. You're probably trying to parse your site error page as CSS.