# CSS fails to load in IE10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

The Error I get on my [website](http://www.ilovetrolls.org/) in IE console  is

```
SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch
```

Seems the CSS is not getting loaded at all.

I have researched a lot.There are quite a few questions on this around the web, but there is no conclusive fix.

Microsoft official [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/hh180764(v=vs.85).aspx) says to add `type="text/css"`  attribute to the link tag, but in my case, I have already added it, in vain.

Is there any fix to this?

Comment: Post your code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: answer is maybe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087170/sec7113-css-was-ignored-due-to-mime-type-mismatch

Comment: @user3830694 i don't have access to server side coding as mentioned in that url :(

Comment: This is due the server configuration from which you're loading your stuff. For example this file (`https://myrevealjs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css/normalize.css`) is transfered as `plain/text` because it's an svn repo. Download the files, put it on your webspace and you're problems are gone.

Comment: @Michel In most cases the server in use is an Apache Webserver and you can configure that one through an .htaccess file; see the answer below.

Comment: @feeela Unfortunately i am using blogger and have no access to server side

Comment: @gearsdigital oh ya.....thanks a lot..seems the solution is quite there in it

Comment: http://helplogger.blogspot.de/2014/03/how-to-add-css-to-blogger-via-template-designer.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `Content-Type` http header to `text/css`. With [htaccess](/questions/tagged/htaccess):

```
AddType text/css css
```

Comment: Unfortunately i am using blogger and have no access to server side.